# Simple Javascript Image

Tags: javascript, image

```
`jQuery('#resultWorkingDays').html(numberWithCommas(resultWorkingDays) + ' days')`
```

Using above prints 'days' on the end of a string. I want to change 'days' to an image source. I've searched & tried a lot of different things but none seem to work.

Complete JS novice, help much appreciated

Comment: What are those things you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

Just include the HTML.

```
jQuery('#resultWorkingDays').html(numberWithCommas(resultWorkingDays) + ' <img src="yourImage.jpg">');
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried all but that it seems, you have to start somewhere, many thanks

Comment: We were all beginners once. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#resultWorkingDays").html(numberWithCommas(resultWorkingDays) + "<img src='\images\...\name.png />");
```

Comment: Hi, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and try to provide some explanation for this snippet, please.
Thanks.